The issue with aggregation and grouping in Sequelize
My task is to multiply the quantity * price fields, and select the "price", "quantity", "product_id" fields. Also group by date in createdAt. But in this code I get the following error: "error: column "ProductsOfOutgoingInvoice.price" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function". If I add the fields "price", "quantity", "product_id" to the group field, then the error disappears, but the grouping by date disappears. Help me decide to select the fields “price”, “quantity”, “product_id” when sampling, but also to group all requests by date
const productsOfOutgoingInvoice: any = await connection.transaction(
        async (transaction: Transaction) => {
            return ProductsOfOutgoingInvoice.findAll({
                raw: true,
                attributes: [
                    [Sequelize.fn("DATE", Sequelize.col("createdAt")), "date"],
                    [Sequelize.literal("SUM(quantity * price)"), "summ"],
                    "price",
                    "quantity",
                    "product_id"
                ],
                group: [Sequelize.fn("DATE", Sequelize.col("createdAt"))],
                transaction
            });
        }
    );


Error
Error: column "ProductsOfOutgoingInvoice.price" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function


When you select createdAt into the query you change their name by date that why it is not able to group it.

I removed this parameter from the query [Sequelize.fn("DATE", Sequelize.col("createdAt")), "date"], but the error persists. And I need to both retrieve the fields and maintain the grouping of records.
